# Read Python data into C++ code

Tags: c++, python-3.x, types, bin

I'm updating a python code and a c++ code so that the second can read data delivered from the first, use it to run before resending its updated data to the original python code. 
More precisely:
- My python file makes a list data[2][5]:

```
data = [[Cij[0, 0],Cij[0,1],Cij[0,2],Cij[2,2],Cij[3,3]],[50,50,100,100,0]]
```

the Cij being floats and I want to save it in a bin file, open it in C++ and access that data in order to modify it. 
Then, I'm saving this modified data into another bin file to read it on my python code. 
I want to do this using the least external libraries as possible since the point of the code is to make it public so easy to use. Any ideas ?

i've been running in data errors, my c++ code reading what seems to be completely wrong numbers from the bin file. However, the second part (python reading the modified data from the bin generated by c++) seems to work.

What I'm currently doing is using pickle to dump the data in a bin and then I access it on c++ doing:

```
DataFile.open('Binpath', ios::binary|ios::in);
float data[2][5];
DataFile.read((char*)&data,sizeof(data));
```

But when I print data in the C++ file, its completely wrong.

So here is a full example: 
In python, I'm writing:

```
import pickle
data = [[1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1], [2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2]]
outfile = open("test.bin", 'wb')
pickle.dump(data, outfile)
outfile.close()
```

and in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream DataFile;
    DataFile.open("test.bin", ios::binary|ios::in);
    if(!DataFile.is_open()){
        cout<< "error"<<endl;
    }
    float data[2][4] = {{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}};
    DataFile.read((char*)&data,sizeof(data));

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    cout << data[0][i]<< endl;}
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        cout << data[1][i]<< endl;}
    cin.ignore();
    DataFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

the printing results are wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `(char*)&data`  This is the calling card of bad things about to happen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you be so kind to share your python export code. I.e. make a [mcve], so we can reproduce your issue. You are talking about `float`s, then generating an 2D array of `doubles`, effectively pointers, then converting the array to a `char` pointer. Bad. Why don't you inline the C++ code in Python? Also look at [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Why do use datatype `double` for `data` and read data as `char`? Can you change datatype of `data` to `char`?

Comment: you are right this a typo. I corrected it. It should be "float data[2][5]"
But I still have an error. For the (char*) data, it is because the .read method requires a char*. I found this solution on internet but it doesn't seem to work for my case.

Comment: Being a little bit more constructive, `Cij being floats` + `double data[2][5];`    how are you so sure that the size (and format) of these 2 variables are the same?  The first thing I'd do when debugging this, is make sure that I read the right amount of data per variable ... but really, you need a debugger to make sure that your file has what you're expecting in it.

Comment: I understand It should be a data structure problem but I don't know how to debug this and bypass it since I NEED to read data in C++ as a char*...

Comment: Again, as stated in the page help section: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**". Please add a [mcve], so we be help you debug your code.

Comment: if you are using `pickle` to write data then you need to implement `unpickle` in C++ to read the data, you can't just map a python 2D list to C++ 2D array.

Comment: @JHBonarius Actually, I think your solution may work! I will look at it right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So consider the Python data array

```py
data = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], [50, 50, 100, 100, 0]]
```

A 2D array which you want to import in C++. The problem is already the data types:

```py
type(data[0][0])
Out[6]: float

type(data[1][0])
Out[7]: int
```

You will need to convert everything to float if you want to import it into a float array. You can use the `array` package for that. However, we'll have to flatten the array in the way C++ stores the multidimensional array:

```py
from array import array
dataArray = array('f', [item for sublist in data for item in sublist])
outputFile = open('outData', 'wb')
dataArray.tofile(outputFile)
outputFile.close()
```

In C++ we can now read the floats from the file using filestream

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float data[2][5];
    std::ifstream dataFile;
    dataFile.open("outData", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    dataFile.read((char*)&data, sizeof(data));
    dataFile.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            std::cout << "(" << i << ", " << j << ") = " << data[i][j] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
(0, 0) = 0.1
(0, 1) = 0.2
(0, 2) = 0.3
(0, 3) = 0.4
(0, 4) = 0.5
(1, 0) = 50
(1, 1) = 50
(1, 2) = 100
(1, 3) = 100
(1, 4) = 0
```

This is just a prove of concept. This can be done much nicer of course...

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it works perfectly and is so clear!

Comment: @MatthieuBeaudet thank you. You could consider accepting my answer then. By the way that it is very easy to screw this up. If you change the size or datatype of `data`, the function will fail.